# Overridng OnMouseClick of PictureBox as a member

Tags: c#, image, forms, picturebox, onmouseclick

I currently have a matrix which contains a members of my class called `furniture`
In this `Furniture` i have a PictureBox member which i want to override it's OnMouseClick method
where do i do that ?
In the `Furniture` class code ?
What is the syntax for overriding such a member ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean *overriding* there is no other place to do then in your custom class:

Create a new `MyPictureBox` class, derived from original `PictureBox`.

Example:

```
public class MyPictureBox : PictureBox {

    public override void OnMouseClick(...)  {
       //...
    }

}
```

and after, naturally, use *this* object in your form:

```
Furniture.Controls.Add(new MyPictureBox ());
```

Don't know what is `Furniture` control *really*, so this is just theoretical example.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to detect the clicks, you just need to add a handler for PictureBox.MouseDown

You can do this in the designer - find the picture box, check its properties and select the "Events" then type in a name for the MouseDown handler.

Note that this is different from actually overriding OnMouseClick, but I suspect you don't really want to do that...

What is your reason for wanting to override OnMouseClick?

Answer (score 0):

Please see following code.

```
public class DerivedPictureBox: PictureBox
{
    protected override void OnMouseClick(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseClick(e);
    }
}
```

Whenever you use DerivedPictureBox in your application, it will execute this derived OnMouseClick method.

Comment: Can you please expand your answer ?  Let's assume my member is called m_image, will the override happen only when clicking the PictureBox property ?